# Access: How to find a field in a whole database?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an access database with many tables. I am looking for a field which may or may not exist in one or many of the tables. How do I check if it exists or not? (without querying each table of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a schema for fields:

```
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

SelectFieldName = "SomeFieldName" 

'Get names of all tables that have a column = SelectFieldName '
Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, SelectFieldName))
```

From: [MS Access: How to bypass/suppress an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277340/ms-access-how-to-bypasssuppress-an-error#277612)

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* do not want to open any table, a solution is to use the `tabledefs` collection of the database object. Each `tabledef` item has its own `fields` collection that you can browse. It would give something like that:

```vb
Public function findFieldInDatabase(p_myFieldName)
    dim db as database, _
        tb as tabledef, _
        fd as field

    set db = currentDb
    for each tb in db.tabledefs
        for each fd in tb.fields
            if fd.name = p_myFieldName then
                debug.print tb.name, fd.name
            end if
        next fd
    next tb
    set fd = nothing
    set tb = nothing
    set db = nothing
end function
```

This code could be easily adapted to accept an optional `p_myTableName` as an argument to limit the search to a table/range of tables.

Comment: Philippe, Why do you do that ", _" trick with your dim's? Is there some huge advantage over multiple dim's?

Comment: BIBD, it's just a clean way to stack the declarations vertically without having to repeat the "Dim" keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do if I wanted to see if a particular column (identified in strSearch) in a particular table.

```vb
Public Sub search()

Dim db As Database
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rsResults As Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim cols As Integer

    strSearch = "a3"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "select * from bar"
    Set rsResults = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    If Not rsResults.BOF Then
        rsResults.MoveFirst
    End If

    cols = rsResults.Fields.Count - 1 ' -1 because we start counting cols at 0
    For i = 0 To cols
        If rsResults(i).Name = strSearch Then
            MsgBox "Found the seach string"
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "end of script"

End Sub
```

Now I know you don't want to write one of those for each table. So the next thing to do would be to loop through all the tables. You can find a list of all the tables with the following SQL

```sql
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    MSysObjects 
WHERE 
    (Left([Name],1)<>"~") 
    AND (Left([Name],4) <> "MSys") 
    AND ([Type] In (1, 4, 6))
```

Connecting these two pieces up together, I'll leave as an exercise for the student :)

Comment: There is an easier way using ADO Schemas

Comment: But if the code is running in Access that requires an additional library reference (unless you use late binding, I guess). The context in which the code will run was not made clear by the original questioner. To me, DAO is the obvious first choice for Jet data if you're working in Access itself.

Comment: my ', _' trick is just a formatting rule for variable declaration. Makes things more readable. You can also use the same trick when enumerating a function's parameters. Another 'school' is www.stackoverflow.com/questions/166657/do-you-have-your-own-dnutndt-do-not-use-thisnever-do-that-list#166717

Comment: Yes, I often do that with functions where the parameters that extend it beyond 80 characters. I'm still inclined to do a separate dim on each line. I was just hoping there was some noticeable advantage to it (like execution speed), but each to his own.

Comment: "To me, DAO is the obvious first choice for Jet data". But in this particular case surely the ADO solution is preferable because OpenSchema returns a recordset consisting only of matches. The DAO involves a lot of looping to find the matches yourself. The extra reference is not expensive!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you access the table schema in MS Access using VBScript:

```vb
TestData = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\somefolder\YOURDB.mdb"
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open TestData

Set rs = Conn.OpenSchema(4)

do until Rs.eof
    tn = RS("TABLE_NAME")
    fn = RS("COLUMN_NAME")
    ' your script goes here
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```vb
Public Function fTableExists(ByVal vstrTable As String) As Boolean
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentProject.Connection.OpenSchema( _
           adschematables, Array(Empty, Empty, vstrTable))
    fTableExists = Not rs.EOF
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function

Public Function fColumnExists(ByVal vstrTable As String, _
                              ByVal vstrColumn As String) As Boolean
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentProject.Connection.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
      Array(Empty, Empty, vstrTable, vstrColumn))
    fColumnExists = Not rs.EOF
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: And perhaps a short explanation on how to use these functions would be helpful. Especially these function seem to assume an open database connection.

Answer (score -1):

MSSQL 
Looking for ADDRESS1 column:
select so.name from sysobjects so
where so.id in (select sc.id from syscolumns sc where name like 'ADDRESS1')

ORACLE
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_metadata

Google will find the syntax for other DBs...

Comment: The database is ms-access. It says so in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

What type of database is it?  If it's SQL Server you can try this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U' AND name = 'myTable'
```

But since it's the column you're looking for and not a table (thanks Brian), try this:

```sql
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    so.[name] AS 'Table',
    sc.[name] AS 'Column' 
    FROM 
        syscolumns sc
    JOIN
        sysobjects so
        ON
            so.id = sc.id
    WHERE 
        sc.[name] = 'myTable'
```

Comment: He's looking for a column not a table.  Close though.

Comment: The database is ms-access. It says so in the original post.

Comment: No, it says so in the modified post.  The original post did not say so.